# Activity get child fragment's input state

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello!

[Layout_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9piO.png)
The picture above is my Layout.

There are nested Fragments and one submit button in MainActivity .

Every Fragment is created by its parent Fragment or activity(the outermost Fragment).

Now I want to do is that as soon as submit button is clicked(OnClickListener is in MainActivity), go to check the input state in the innermost Fragment(green). (and go to next activity if the state is valid).

Actually I have a solution and it works,it is use getChildFragmentManager() in MainActivity repeatedly till I get the innermost Fragment, and call innermost Fragment's method to verify state and return result.

I want to know is there any more efficient or simple way to do this?

Thank you.